# How to implement a self referencing (parent_id) model in cakephp

Tags: database-design, cakephp

I have a table called categories. The table holds categories and their sub(subsub)categories...

Its an easy table:

- id
- parent_id
- title

This way I can make categories with endless depth... I kinda hoped that cakephp would understand parent_id (I also tried category_id, but that makes cakePHP join on itself :D )

What is the right way to tackle this?

NOTE: There is also a 'many to many' table called places. Those places can belong to one or more categories.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tree behaviour is overkill for this situation. You just need to set your model up like this:

```
class Category extends AppModel {

  public $hasMany = array(
    'Children'=>array(
       'className'=>'Category',
       'foreignKey'=>'parent_id'
    )
  );

  public $belongsTo = array(
    'Parent'=>array(
       'className'=>'Category',
       'foreignKey'=>'parent_id'
    )
  );

}
```

Now, when you do a find() on Category, you'll get two additional Models called Parent (which points to the parent id) and Children (which lists it's children).

Comment: Hey Richard, I was looking for the tree behaviour, but I agree it can be overkill. Anyways. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Thanks! It's very simple when properly illustrated!

Answer (score 5):

Look at the [tree behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1339/Tree); with MPTT logic. The link supplied to Oracle's website is dead; but you can find a bunch of material about how to use it on the [cake manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1341/Basic-Usage) and [online](http://ad7six.com/2007/03/26/Working-with-Tree-data-%28MPTT%29.html).

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id INTEGER(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id INTEGER(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    lft INTEGER(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    rght INTEGER(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);
```

Just make sure your table matches that structure for best results within Cake and it's baking.

Comment: Thanks man, interesting stuff, and indeed exactly what I need. Everything is set up smoothly!

Comment: In a lot of instances this is overkill. A simple self-referencing table as mentioned below by Anh Pham with the appropriate associations is more than adequate in the majority of causes. Tree behaviour does become increasingly useful as the levels of "depth" goes beyond on level (ie: children can have children).

Answer (score 2):

In Category model: belongsTo Parent and hasMany Children, both have the class 'Category' and foreign key 'parent_id'

Answer (score 1):

the following  `custom recursive function tree()` worked for me

```
public function index() {
    $c = $this->tree();
    debug($c);
    exit;
}


function tree($parent=null){
    $arr  = array();
    $categories = $this->Category->find('all',array(
         'conditions'=>array('Category.parent_id '=> $parent)
    ));
    foreach($categories as $key => $category){           
        $arr[$category['Category']['id']]['title'] = $category['Category']['name'];             
        $arr[$category["Category"]["id"]]['children'] = $this->tree($category['Category']['id'] );
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RichardAtHome's answer is the right one.
In CakePHP 3.+ you write:

```
     $this->hasMany('Children', [
            'className'=>'Category',
            'foreignKey'=>'parent_id'
     ]);

    $this->belongsTo('Parent', [
        'className'=>'Category',
        'foreignKey'=>'parent_id'
    ]);
```

and don't forger to use 'contain' in your 'find', e.g.:

```
        $categories = $this->find("all")
           ->order(...)
           ->contain(['Children']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Related question - assume I have a 3 level self-referencing hierarchy implemented as advised by @RichardAtHome - I understand when I try to find a particular Category it will also get me the parent category and all children categories. However how can I make it find the path back to root? Is there some clean trick to accomplish this or will require a custom hack?

I imagine using this in a scenarios where the Product table has one category ID associated with it but when displaying to users I would like to also display the entire parent chain so that they can see something like 'confectionaries/seasonal/nestle' - and then the user can alter the entire product hierarchy